# Compiling mex files fails using shell script

Tags: linux, matlab, mex

I have some mex files, which until recently were working perfectly. They require some compiler flags which matlab won't pass using the ordinary `mex` command, so I've been using a shell script to compile them, accomplished from within matlab using `!sh mexfile_compile.sh`. This has worked fine for about a year.

I've recently found (with no change to the version of GCC or g++ I have installed), that my files won't compile any more; I get the error `sh: 0: Can't open mexfile_compile.sh`, even if I run matlab as root.

Interestingly, if I run `!ls | grep mexfile_compile.sh` on the active directory from the matlab prompt, I get a single result: `mexfile_compile.sh.save`, though if I run the same command (without the `!`) in a normal terminal window, I don't get the `.save` at the end. It's worth pointing out that the script runs perfectly well from the terminal using `sh mexfile_compile.sh`.

Does anyone know what's going on here or how I can fix it?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is, the current directory in MATLAB is different from the directory in terminal. Otherwise it does not make sense.

Comment: They're the same directory! I even removed some sub-folders from the matlab path which weren't necessary for the operation in question, and still I'm getting the same results, and it's happening on both my lab machine and my office machine.. I'm running Debian Wheezy (old-stable), so I'm going to give Jessie (stable) and Stretch (testing) a go and see if that helps...